# Visual Studio Android Google Test Project Setup

Tags: android, c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, android-ndk

I have a normal native cpp activity application project set up in VS2015, i.e.:

- Android Project -> C++ code used to build a .so file
- AndroidPackaging Project -> java / manifest stuff references the .so to create the apk.

I would like to add some unit tests using google test for the C++ code (not java or jni) in the .so to run on an Android device.

How would I set up a project to do this? ([looking at this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/sources/third_party/googletest/README.NDK) it appears to be building an executable rather than an apk, and I can't see a suitable Visual Studio Project template to do that).

Do I have to set up a makefile project? How would I ensure the build environment (target API level, C++ features etc.) is the same as my actual project? I don't really have much clue when it comes to makefiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually seems quite simple to add a new "executable" configuration type for Clang by editing the existing MSBuild xml files in the `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Application Type\Android\2.0\` folder.

Make sure to back these up before changing them to avoid breaking anything.

---

File: **`1033/general_android.xml`**, line 80, add:

```
<EnumValue Name="Executable" DisplayName="Executable" Description="Executable" />
```

(Adds the "Executable" option to the Configuration Type dropdown menu in Project Properties > General).

File: **`Android.Common.targets`**, change line 325:

```
<ProjectTools Condition="'$(ConfigurationType)' == 'DynamicLibrary' or '$(ConfigurationType)' == 'Executable'" Include="Link" />
```

(Makes the Project Properties > Linker menu available for the executable configuration type).

File: **`Android.Common.props`**, add to ~line 85:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(ConfigurationType)' == 'Executable'">
    <LinkCompiled>true</LinkCompiled>
    <TargetExt></TargetExt>
    <OutputType>exe</OutputType>
    <TargetName Condition="'$(TargetName)' == ''">$(RootNamespace)</TargetName>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

---

This should result add the executable option here:

[image: Executable Configuration Type]

The usual project property settings can be used to add extra include directories / library dependencies etc. You may have to manually add -fPIE and -pie to the linker command line options, and change the Output File option to $(TargetPath).

The google test project can then be built separately as a static or shared lib and linked in. The resulting executable can be run on a device with commands similar to [the ones described here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/sources/third_party/googletest/README.NDK).

I haven't yet got this launching under a debugger.